# Passing and using a parameter in a script in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer,
I want to call a script like this:

`@"path\to\script.sql" develop`

and use the value `develop` in my script as a table prefix like this:

`SELECT * FROM <parameter>_table;` which should then evaluate to `SELECT * FROM develop_table`

Is something like this possible in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

See the article below. It will answer your question.

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#2_7

I'll make an example for you, based off that blog article.

Creating a dummy table:

```
CREATE TABLE t(x NUMBER, t VARCHAR2(255));
INSERT INTO t(x, t) VALUES (1, 'Example');
COMMIT;
```

The script below has been saved in ***C:\Users\William***. The filename is ***example.sql***.

```
SELECT *
  FROM &1
;
```

Now, from SQL Developer, I execute:

```
@C:\Users\William\example.sql t
```

Note that when you pass a parameter to a script like this, you are passing the text value that is stored in implicitly-named substitution variables. The substitution variable is named according to its order (e.g., &1 then &2 then &3 etc.).

This is the script output:

```
old:SELECT *
  FROM &1

new:SELECT *
  FROM t

 X T         
-- ----------
 1 Example
```

You should probably take some time to consider other solutions to the problem you are solving. You may not need to execute a *script* via SQL developer. Perhaps you'd be better off creating a procedure that generates dynamic SQL, based off parameters you feed to the procedure. You would then use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on the dynamic SQL statement inside the procedure.

I personally might find that technique more useful when performing actions like ETL (as opposed to queries). Then again, I'm no expert, and there're probably even better solutions out there.

Comment: Thanks!
This is supposed to be used for a one-time-job script. Not something we are going to do regularly. The parameter is just to simplify testing the scripts between evironments.